# Make a button inactive for a certain time

Tags: javascript

Ok... I'm making and incremental game to test my JS skills and I'm already facing problems... button timeout ! So here are some details about my problem:

I have a div that I use as a button and it allow the user to "go to work". I would like the button to be inactive during the time he is at work. Then when the time necessary for his work would be met the player would receive money and the div would reactivate.

my html div (button class is for my css):

```
<div class="button" onClick="makeMoney()" id="makeMoney">
<span>Go To Work</span></div>
```

my Js function:

```
function makeMoney() {
money += job;
document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
};
```

Comment: Please show one of those "lot of things".

Comment: Well I don't have the code anymore, but it was probably just me that wasn't able to adapt the code I found to my code... anyway Reed Spool gave me a very good solution to my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
function makeMoney() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("makeMoney");

    // If the button is currently disabled, do nothing
    // We can't go to work twice!
    if (btn.getAttribute('disabled') == 'disabled') {
       return;
    }

    // Disable the button immediately
    btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')

    // Then, after some time...
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Make money and...
        money += job;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;

        // Re-enable the button so it can be clicked again
        btn.removeAttribute('disabled')

    }, 1000) // 1 second in milliseconds
};
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I needed except for the # in  
document.getElementById("#makeMoney");
it works like a charm without it

Comment: Neat! Good catch (I didn't check my work :-x). Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this?

```
setTimeout(function(){
// Do whatever you want after that time.
),1000); // Wait 1s
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` for timed events. Also, your button isn't really a button, but rather a div. Because of this, I am leaving the disable/enable functionality up to you.

```
function makeMoney() {
    money += job;
    document.getElementById('money').innerHTML = money;

    disableButton();
    setTimeout(enableButton, 1000);
}

function disableButton() {
    // foo
}

function enableButton() {
    // bar
}
```

Comment: Keizom want to complement you on writing solid answer, similar to mine at the same time. Also want to complement you on your current reputation and avatar.

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<button id="testButton" onclick="makeMoney()">Go To Work</button>
```

Javascript

```
function makeMoney()
{
    document.getElementById('testButton').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(
        function()
        {
            document.getElementById('testButton').removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
        , 3000)
    alert("money made");
}
```

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jct1uzye/1/